# Crontab not running 24 hours

Tags: cron, tcpdump

I've the following job in `/etc/crontab`:

```
@hourly root /usr/bin/script
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall tcpdump
date=$(date +%G%m%d-%k%M)
tcpdump -n port 5060 -w /media/SIPTraces/filename-$date.pcap -s 0 &
```

This runs beautifully(ish).

However, eventhough I have the `@hourly` time parameter, it only runs hourly between 10am and midnight. It clearly stops the job (or runs it) as the `TCPDUMP` file ends at midnight. But then another file is not created until 10am the next day.

Any ideas?